# Softaculous Ampps and Webuzo not working

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, root, lamp, trash

I was pretty hasty in doing these installations, so I can't remember the process completely, and can't find the instructions either.
But the `chmod` was involved.

I found them both under `/usr/local/`

I can't start or delete either.

**Ampps** wants me to run it as root? How? If it would be smart.

**Webuzo** just doesn't do anything. Not with the IP and not with the executable file.

Can you give me some advice on how to start one or the other, or at least to delete them?

And if you know of any easy to use ampp stacks, that would be great. I don't want to fuss to much with installations of web apps.

**Update:**

I ran `sudo nautulis` and managed to delete those to useless installs.

But now they are stuck in my trash, and I can't delete them. Not even with nautulis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trash can is a folder under your Home called: .local/share/Trash

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Will set the ownership of the files in the trash to the account you are using.  After that you should be able to empty the trash.